Does there exist an HFD which is not a Mori domain?
A half factorial domain (HFD) is an integral domain such that every nonzero nonunit $x$ admits a factorisation into irreducibles, and any two factorisations of $x$ have the same number of factors.
A Mori domain is an integral domain with ACC on divisorial ideals.
Does there exist an HFD which is not Mori?
What have I tried? Essentially every construction of HFDs I can find. Most HFDs come from Krull domains (eg with class group size $≤2$), and the easiest one the doesn't is ℤ[√-3]. Krull and Noetherian both imply Mori, so that's a bad start.
More promisingly I've looked at HFDs coming from the $D+M$ construction, and $R[x]$ where $R$ is a Krull domain with class group size $≤2$. Every example of this I've been able to compute has been Mori, but it's conceivable that there's something here.
It is of course also plausible that HFD implies Mori. If it were true though, then Mori would lie strictly between HFD and BFD as classes of integral domains. This would be remarkable (in my opinion), and I would have thought this statement would be easier to find in the literature if true.
